# Import data files in spark on desktop

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter

I am very new to spark and I am using it with Jupyter. Now I want to import the shakespeare.txt file and run the following code

```
from __future__ import print_function
from operator import add

# Use the SparkContext sc here, see below.
lines = sc.textFile("C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\Spark_Testing\Gutenberg\shakespeare.txt")

counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
              .reduceByKey(add)

output = counts.collect()

# Print the first 100 word counts as pairs
for (word, count) in output[:100]:
    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
```

For this I am getting the following error. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-41cbbaab4214> in <module>()
      5 lines = sc.textFile("C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\Spark_Testing\Gutenberg\shakespeare.txt")
      6 
----> 7 counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' '))               .map(lambda x: (x, 1))               .reduceByKey(add)
      8 
      9 output = counts.collect()

C:\spark-1.3.1\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in reduceByKey(self, func, numPartitions)
   1480         [('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
   1481         """
-> 1482         return self.combineByKey(lambda x: x, func, func, numPartitions)
   1483 
   1484     def reduceByKeyLocally(self, func):

C:\spark-1.3.1\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in combineByKey(self, createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners, numPartitions)
   1691         """
   1692         if numPartitions is None:
-> 1693             numPartitions = self._defaultReducePartitions()
   1694 
   1695         serializer = self.ctx.serializer

C:\spark-1.3.1\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in _defaultReducePartitions(self)
   2074             return self.ctx.defaultParallelism
   2075         else:
-> 2076             return self.getNumPartitions()
   2077 
   2078     def lookup(self, key):

C:\spark-1.3.1\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in getNumPartitions(self)
    319         2
    320         """
--> 321         return self._jrdd.partitions().size()
    322 
    323     def filter(self, f):

C:\spark-1.3.1\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\spark-1.3.1\python\lib\py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o311.partitions.
ajarshi.bhadra/Desktop/Spark_Testing/Gutenberg/shakespeare.txt
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.partitions(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you please change this line to see if it helps
lines = sc.textFile("file:\\\C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\Spark_Testing\Gutenberg\shakespeare.txt")

Comment: I tried. Got the same error

Comment: I checked protocol.py
https://github.com/bartdag/py4j/blob/master/py4j-python/src/py4j/protocol.py
It looks like \r from rajarshi in path is causing issue probably, look closely at the error it says "ajarshi.bhadra/Desktop/Spark_Testing/Gutenberg/shakespeare.txt".
Please add 2 slashes to remove \r(carriage return interpretation).
So make your path like this
lines = sc.textFile("file:\\\C:\Users\\\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\Spark_Testing\Gutenberg\shak‌​espeare.txt")
I am setting up spark on windows to test this.
Let me know

Comment: It gave the same error. It worked when I put the gutenberg folder inside spark-1.3.1 which is my SPARK_HOME. To be precise when I did this sc.textFile("C:\spark-1.3.1\Data_Work\Gutenberg\shakespeare.txt")

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I put the gutenberg folder as a subfolder inside spark-1.3.1 which is my SPARK_HOME. To be precise when I did this

```
sc.textFile("C:\spark-1.3.1\Data_Work\Gutenberg\shakespeare.txt")
```

after creating the appropriate directories